# Can I add the constant of integration when and wherever I want?

Tags: integration

Lets consider this simple differential equation:
$dy/dx=\beta y\ ;\ y(0)=2$

The solution is: $ln(y)=\beta x$

From this points I have two options, adding $C$ and then find $y$ or first find $y$ and then adding $C$:

a) $ln(y)=\beta x+C\Rightarrow y=e^{\beta x+C} \Rightarrow y=e^{C} e^{\beta x} \Rightarrow \mathbf{y=Ce^{\beta x}}$

b) $\mathbf{y=e^{\beta x}+C}$

And with boundary conditions:

a) $\mathbf{y=2e^{\beta x}}$

b) $\mathbf{y=e^{\beta x}+1}$

(a) and (b) are different functions, so is it correct/not correct to add the constant whenever I want? Am I missing something here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does $lan(y)$ mean $\ln(y)$?

Comment: Yes, I've edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constant of integration, $C$, must go in front, as in $y = Ce^{\beta t}$, and not added, as in $y = e^{\beta t} + C$.  This is because, if $y = e^{\beta t} + C$, then, $y' = \beta e^{\beta t} \ne \beta*y = \beta*(e^{\beta t} + C)$.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I guess I had a misconception, its been long time since I studied it.

Answer (score 1):

I think the derivation in a) will be more clear if we include a step that has been omitted. We first note that
$$
\frac{y'(x)}{y(x)} = \beta
$$
(assuming that $y(x)$ is not zero).
*Then* we take antiderivatives of both sides, concluding that
$$
\ln(y(x)) = \beta x + C
$$
for some constant $C$. (Here we are also assuming that $y(x)$ is always positive.)

It follows that
$$
y(x) = e^{\beta x + C} = K e^{\beta x}
$$
(where $K = e^C$).

We can now use the initial condition $y(0) = 2$ to conclude that
$y(x) = 2 e^{\beta x}$.

One can't just add a constant of integration wherever one wants. The fact is that the general antiderivative of a continuous function $f$ on an interval $I$ is $F(x) + C$, where $F$ is any particular antiderivative of $f$. Because of this fact, we must carefully to remember to include "$+C$" when taking antiderivatives (but not at other times when we are not taking antiderivatives).

Comment: Ok, thank you very much, I guess I had a misconception, its been long time since I studied it.